# how to get opacity value of the area where clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to getOpacity value of the area where the user has clicked because I want to compare it with the drawable opacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This .... This works and If you have Imageview get ImageView as drawable then convert it to bitmap drawable

BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) drawable.getDrawable();
int alpha = Color.alpha(bd.getBitmap().getPixel(evet.getX(), event.getY()));